# Conditional validation for ActiveModel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a situation where I need to validate some fields for one method and all fields for another method.

This is how my model looks at the moment:

```
class User < ActiveInteraction::Base

def initialize
  full_validation = true
end

# All user related auth data
string :email
string :password
string :name
string :surname
string :phone

@error
@full_validation
attr_accessor :error, :full_validation

# Validation rules
validates :email,
  presence: true,
  format: {
    with: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/,
    :multiline => true
  }

validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

validates :name, presence: true,
  format: {
    with: /^[a-zA-Z\d\s]*$/,
    :multiline => true
  }, :if => :full_validation?

validates :surname, presence: true,
  format: {
    with: /^[a-zA-Z\d\s]*$/,
    :multiline => true
  }, :if => :full_validation?

validates :phone, presence: true, :if => :full_validation?
```

If I call `user = User.new` and then call `user.full_validation = false` then only email and password fields should be validated however the if statements in the validation for name, surname and phone completely ignore this and return validation errors.

I also tried few other approaches all work (no errors) but still validate all fields:

```
def isFullValidation
  full_validation == true
end
```

I also tried using with_options and wrap the 3 validation rules in `if: :full_validation? do .. end` statement.

Comment: Where is `full_validation?` defined?

Comment: @Stefan I tried :full_validation it did not work either. No error or exception just does not skip validation for surname, name and phone fields.

Comment: That is very strange. Calling an undefined method should raise an exception.

Comment: @Stefan https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cf9639461e549697c8e2 this is how I have it now the problem is that the method is_full_validation is never called. I added puts & logger in the method but nothing comes out of it suggesting it's never actually called in the with_options statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using grouping conditional validation

```
with_options if: Proc.new { |u| u.is_full_validation? } do |user|
  user.validates ... # pay attention to the 'user.' in front of each validation!!
  user.validates ...
end

def is_full_validation?
  full_validation == true
end
```

Comment: What's up with the camelCased method name??

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune LOL, you're right! I just copy-and-pasted the method from the question, but YES! Rails has his conventions and is better to follow them. Let me change the answer

Comment: This was my attempt as well but it does not work. I inserted puts full_validation just above the return full_validation == true. And full_validation is set to false however the validation for those fields within with_options statement is still done resulting in validation errors.

Comment: In your question you tried the same, but you forgot the `?` at the end of the method. In rails, `?` is part of the method name

Comment: @iMacTia https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cf9639461e549697c8e2 This is how I have it now. I do have the ? sign but still same problem. I made sure that after I create a new instance of the object I also call user.full_validation = false.

Comment: At this point, I'm wondering if `ActiveInteraction` supports conditional validations...

Comment: It includes ActiveModel I would assume wouldn't it two an error or exception otherwise ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64884/discussion-between-sterling-duchess-and-imactia).